# Parallax Effect - change speed of element in mid-scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax

I am building a parallax home page for a client and currently using Stellar.js.

There is a div called `#slide2` in the middle of the page at width `100%` and starts at `650px` tall. Another div called #slide3, also `width: 100%`, is just below `#slide2`. `#slide3` scrolls up faster than normal in front of `#slide2`.

The designer on the project wants `#slide2` to 'shrink until it is 350px tall'. Now, this would mean that `#slide3`, below it, has to scroll up at one speed - fast so that it encompasses part of `#slide2` behind it - and then suddenly scroll at another speed - normal speed, so that it does not cover up more than `300px` of `#slide2`.

I have tried using jQuery to write a different 'data-stellar-ratio' into the element, mid-scroll, to make it suddenly move at a different speed. It doesn't work though. The attribute shows up in the code but the speed remains unchanged.

I have also tried triggering a resize event via scrolling - i.e. `#slide2` literally shrinks to 350px and `#slide3` does not pass in front of #slide2 at all - but that's not what the designer wants. Additionally, the resize event only happens once and the page has to be refreshed to see it again, which is also a no-no.

So, here's my problem: *I don't think that what they're asking me to do is actually possible with any current parallax plugin currently in existence.*

And this is why I am posting my question here. Can scroll speed be changed for an element, mid-scroll, on Stellar.js or any other currently available plugin? Or, does someone have any inkling of an idea on how to do it?

Any help at all would be much, much appreciated.

Here's the HTML I am trying to manipulate:

```
<div class="slide" id="slide2" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.2">
</div>

<div class="slide" id="slide3" data-stellar-ratio="2.65" data-stellar-vertical-offset="190">
</div>
```

And here, if it matters, is my Stellar.js code:

```
$(window).stellar({
  horizontalScrolling: false,
  verticalScrolling: true,
  scrollProperty: 'scroll',
  parallaxBackgrounds: true,
  parallaxElements: true,
  hideDistantElements: false
});
```

Comment: Can you put together a working example of what you have tried as a [jsFiddle](jsfiddle.net)?